# S3 vs EC2 access speeds (on average)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

If we consider that all of our users are located within the same geographic area and that we choose the same location from within either an EC2 instance (running a highly optimized instance type) or an S3 bucket, which would be better for serving content ... EC2 or S3? I have a website that's entirely client driven (running client facing Javascript and is entirely limited in its feature-set) so I'm trying to determine which is the better route. I don't need to save assets nor do I need HTTPS. I realize I can consider CloudFront as well, but let's assume I'm not going to use CloudFront for purposes of this question.

Answer (score 4):

As usual, It Depends(tm). Justin Dorfman of MaxCDN, a cache delivery service, [wrote a good analysis of why S3 isn't the best webserver](http://jdorfman.posthaven.com/medium-bitcoin-660x493-dot-jpg-cdn-vs-s3):

[image: Comparing static asset performance between S3 and a CDN]

Ultimately the question may not be entirely answerable either- I'd suggest the real question is, how can I serve static (unchanging) assets most effectively to my end-user clients? It may differ between "first load" and recurring users, and as you mention, a geographic component may play a part.

Certainly S3 (or S3 with a cache on front and appropriate `cache-control` headers) has a advantages in terms of maintainability, scalability, and reducing single points of failure.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a **static website** (no back-end processing), then serving it directly from Amazon S3 would be:

- **More reliable:** Amazon S3 is a regional-based service replicated across multiple Availability Zones, as opposed to a web server that might be a single point of failure
- **Cheaper:** Service directly from S3, no need to run a web server
- **Easier to maintain:** Aside from configuring security, there is no administration required for S3.

Putting **Amazon CloudFront** "in front" of the S3 bucket would also reduce latency for users elsewhere in the world since it caches content in 50+ edge locations. However, if all your users are close to the AWS region from which you are serving content, the gains would not be huge (eg serving out of North Virginia to users in North Virginia).

Comment: Thanks John, but would serving content from S3 be faster than serving it from an EC2 instance? Your logic is sound and much appreciated, but for purposes of speed solely, which would be the better option?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer depends on the average and peak bandwidth required. EC2 instances will get very expensive if you need high network bandwidth. Please be specific on what you require. Unless you have a high traffic web site go with S3. If you have high traffic, this means that you have revenue / budget, then spend the time to evaluate the most appropriate solution. For example, S3 is fault tolerant. For EC2 you will need a load balancer, auto scaling groups, multiple EC2 instances, a DevOps plan to update the images that these instances launch from, etc. etc. etc.